# Nginx, Docker, Django, один сервер и n-микросервисов

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Есть сервер, на нём в Docker запущены (ну допустим) 2 сайтика (в теории их может быть n-сайтов/сервисов). Я хочу чтобы они выглядели так: http://ip-addr/app_1 и http://ip-addr/app_2
Т.е. я хочу указывать через путь к конкретному сервису/сайту на моём сервере.
У меня работает если я использую для каждого сервиса/сайта свой порт: http://ip-addr:1234 и http://ip-addr:4321
Проксрование идёт через Nginx (test_1 и test_2 это мои сайтики в контейнерах)

```
upstream test_1 {
        server web_2:9000;
    }
    server {
        listen 4321;
        location  / {
            proxy_pass http://test_1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
    upstream test_2 {
        server web_2:8000;
    }
    server {
        listen 1234;
        location  / {
            proxy_pass http://test_2;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
```

Вопрос: как правильно настроить конфигурационный файл Nginx чтобы доступ к моим сервисам/сайтам был через путь, а не через порт?
И можно ли это сделать без SSL-сертификата и без доменного имени? Из имеющегося только IP адрес сервера? Нужно ли в docker-compose.yaml мне как-то специально настраивать раздел Nginx?

для варианта с портами сделано так:

```
nginx:
build: ./nginx
ports:
 - 1234:1234
 - 4321:4321
depends_on:
  - web_1
  - web_2
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос: как правильно настроить конфигурационный файл Nginx чтобы доступ к моим сервисам/сайтам был через путь, а не через порт?

Все это делается исключительно средствами Nginx. Ниже будет конфиг.

> И можно ли это сделать без SSL-сертификата и без доменного имени? Из имеющегося только IP адрес сервера?

Можно.

SSL сертификат не нужен, если вам не нужен HTTPS. А если нужен, получите бесплатный на Letsencrypt, вот [интерактивная инструкция](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions), но тогда и домен потребуется прикупить.

> Нужно ли в docker-compose.yaml мне как-то специально настраивать раздел Nginx?

В `docker-compose.yaml` нужно пробросить порт 80:80, тогда будет открываться по IP адресу. Главное, чтобы этот порт был свободен. Если занят, то либо освобождайте, либо делайте проксирование уже на том веб-сервере, который его занял.

```
ports:
 - 80:80
```

### Настройка Nginx

Чтобы раскидать трафик на 2 приложения, в Nginx нужна одна секция server, и 2 location `/app_1` и `/app_2` с проксированием.

Но приложениям будет передаваться путь `/app_1/some-uri`, а если хотите без этого префикса, просто `/some-uri`, то нужно сделать rewrite и немного поменять proxy_pass, ниже так и сделано.

```
upstream test_1 {
    server web_1:9000;
}

upstream test_2 {
    server web_2:8000;
}
    
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location /app_1/ {
        rewrite ^/app_1/(.*)   /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
        proxy_pass             http://test_1$uri;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect         off;
    }

    location /app_2/ {
        rewrite ^/app_2/(.*)   /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
        proxy_pass             http://test_2$uri;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect         off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Но появилась ошибка **502**
Решил изменить строку proxy_pass на `proxy_pass  http://test_1 #$uri;`(убрал $uri) и после этого появилась другая ошибка: `DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'test_1'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.`
В чём может быть проблема?
Спасибо!

Comment: $uri убирать не нужно, потому что иначе в приложение будет адрес передаваться с префиксом. Покажите логи `docker-compose logs -f --tail 100`. Ошибка DisallowedHost - наверное это https://stackoverflow.com/a/40667600/9435985

Comment: web_1_1  | Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'test_1'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
====================
web_1_1  | Bad Request: /
====================
nginx_1  | 95.54.159.235 - - [28/Mar/2021:14:55:12 +0000] "GET /app_1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 58449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: web_2_1  | Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'test_2'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
================
web_2_1  | Bad Request: /
================
nginx_1  | 95.54.159.235 - - [28/Mar/2021:14:55:18 +0000] "GET /app_2/ HTTP/1.1" 400 58315 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS у меня настроено через переменные окружения
D_A_H=localhost 158.ххх.30.ххх
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("D_A_H").split(' ')

Comment: `web_1_1 | Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'test_1'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.` - это я думаю ругается джанга, я с ней не работал, не знаю. А ругается потому что не нравится заголовок Host. Через nginx выставьте тот хост, который вам нужен `proxy_set_header Host $host;`. Я свой пример сделал из вашего, и убрал его. Оказывается, он нужен. Обновил ответ. Но, так как у вас IP адрес, в хосте будет IP адрес, я думаю это подойдет.

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS у меня настроено через переменные окружения D_A_H=localhost 158.ххх.30.ххх` - да, наверное вся ошибка заключалась в Host, и теперь он будет передаваться, и все заработает.

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!
Вы были совершенно правы, последнее решение дало нужный результат
Спасибо!